# reduce vagrant box storage (vmdk) size

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox

I created initialized vagrant from ubuntu/trusty64 on Windows host. 
I realized newly created virtualbox's disk size is set to 40GB. I want to reduce this to at least 10GB. Is there any way to do this?

although right now actual size is 1.19GB i don't want it's virtual size to be this big.

thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to do it by

1. zero-out disk space within the vm by running

`cat /dev/zero > /path/to/fill/z; sync; sleep 3; sync; rm -rf z`

> NOTE: Delete unwanted files within the VM before running the command above. If you have multiple partitions, logical volumes, do it on each of them.

2. compact / shrink the virtual disk (this works fine with VDI format, but not sure about VMDK, you can try)

`VBoxManage modifyhd --compact /path/to/vdisk.vmdk`

You'll see the progress, once finished, check its size.

***Update***:
If you want to resize the virtual disk, you should use `VBoxManage modifyhd --resize <megabytes> /path/to/vdisk.vmdk`.

> NOTE: The size of the virtual disk doesn't matter too much, it is just like a cap (max size) of the virtual disk image it can grow up to. By default the VMDK should be dynamically allocated, which mean the vmdk size will be close to the amount of data within the VM. The above method will help to reclaim spaces that has been freed up within the guest.

**IMPORTANT**: Growing the size of the vdisk is OK, but when reducing/shrinking you should be very careful, there is risk of losing data the new size < the actual data size within the vdisk.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. Problem is its virtual size (max size) is 40GB however actual size on disk is only 1.19GB. I just wanted to reduce this 40GB virtual size. vmdk files seem to grow on the go up until the given max size.

Comment: OK, now I understand what you want to achieve. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you! I tried you method and plus, tried "VBoxManage modifyhd --resize vdisk.vdi" after converting my vdisk.vmdk to vdi format with no luck. Though I was able to shrink it's virtual size to 15G my virtual machine failed booting after shrink. so I just gave up on this for now :(

Comment: Didn't work for me:

    ~/dev/slim
    $ VBoxManage modifyhd --resize 40000 '/Users/jstoutenburg/VirtualBox VMs/dev_default_1434481145698_7671/box-disk1.vmdk'
    0%...
    Progress state: VBOX_E_NOT_SUPPORTED
    VBoxManage: error: Resize hard disk operation for this format is not implemented yet!

Any ideas? I'm doing this on Mac OS host if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2):

On linux you can try using `qemu-img resize filename [+|-]size`

Comment: unfortunately my host system is windows.. Isn't there any way to do this?

Comment: Sorry, I'm unaware of windows methods. If you can find a way to shrink the container I can tell you how to resize the internal filesystem inside of the VM.